# How to change the output of this Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written a simple python password generator:

```
import string
import random

print "Password generator will create a random customizable password."
print "Choose your options wisely."

number = int(raw_input("How many letters do you want in your password?"))
caps = str(raw_input("Do you want capital letters in your password? Y/N:"))
symbols = str(raw_input( "Do you want punctuation and other symbols in your password?    Y/N:"))
otherchoice = str(raw_input( "Do you want numbers in your password? Y/N:"))

punctuation = ("!", ".", ":", ";", ",", "?", "'", "@", "$", "~", "^","%", "#", "&", "/")
numbers = map(str,range(0,10))
stringpunctuation = "".join(punctuation)
stringnumbers = "".join(numbers)
lowercase = string.ascii_lowercase
uppercase = string.ascii_uppercase

if caps == "Y":
    characters = lowercase + uppercase
else:
    characters = lowercase

if symbols == "Y":
    characters += stringpunctuation
if otherchoice == "Y":
    characters += stringnumbers

password = random.sample(characters, number)
print "The password is", password
```

This is an example of what appears in the terminal when I run it:

```
Password generator will create a random customizable password.
Choose your options wisely.
How many letters do you want in your password?15
Do you want capital letters in your password? Y/N:Y
Do you want punctuation and other symbols in your password? Y/N:Y
Do you want numbers in your password? Y/N:Y
The password is ['x', 'p', 'E', 'X', 'V', '#', ',', '@', 'q', 'N', 'F', 'U', 'b', 'W', '.']
```

How can I make it so that the output is something like this (using the password in the example):
`xpEXV#,@qNFUbW.`

I don't really need to know the answer, the practical result will be the same, I'm just super curious.

Answer (score 4):

Join the characters to together with the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join); pick a joining string and call the method on that, passing in your list:

```
password = ''.join(password)
```

This joins the characters with the empty string (`''`):

```
>>> password = ['x', 'p', 'E', 'X', 'V', '#', ',', '@', 'q', 'N', 'F', 'U', 'b', 'W', '.']
>>> ''.join(password)
'xpEXV#,@qNFUbW.'
```

For other uses you could pick a different joiner:

```
>>> '->'.join(password)
'x->p->E->X->V->#->,->@->q->N->F->U->b->W->.'
>>> '...'.join(password)
'x...p...E...X...V...#...,...@...q...N...F...U...b...W....'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel so stupid now, specially since I already knew how to use "".join. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible